# Why isn't my variable preserved in drawRect?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im trying to have an nsview that takes a custom object as an argument, then draws out some text fields based on that object.

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect parent:(id)parent item:(TempObj*)item{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self){
        textDelegate = parent;
        myObject = item;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But by the time it reaches the drawRect, the myObject variable is nil.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (myObject != nil){
        NSTextField* title = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textRoot.x, textRoot.y-20, 200, 20)];
        title.stringValue = [myObject getName];
        title.backgroundColor = [NSColor yellowColor];
        [self addSubview:title];
        NSLog(@"here");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"broken");
    }
}
```

The view is initialized in another class with:

```
 _inventoryItemView = [[InventoryItemView alloc]initWithFrame:_inventoryItemView.frame parent:self item:testObj];
```

Is there some way for me to maintain the variable, or is there something with the scope I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `initWithFrame:parent:item:` is being called for the same instance that's having `drawRect:` called on it?

Comment: You need to override `initWithCoder:` if your view is initialized from nib, @CarlVeazey is right

Comment: I added some logs, and the `initWithFrame:parent:item:` is definitely called, and the variable is not nil. Also, I'm initializing the view from some other code. I'll add where I do that bit above.

Comment: Verify the pointer equality of the two instances though just to make 100% sure... Also check that `myObject` isn't a weak reference...

Comment: I checked, and you are totally right, `drawRect:` uses a new instance. How can I make sure my variables get passed through?

Comment: Show the definition of myObject. Is it maybe declared as weak?

Comment: It started as `@property (strong,nonatomic)TempObj* myObject;` but I also tried it in the `@interface` section and neither way works.

Comment: Where/when are you adding `_inventoryItemView` to the view hierarchy?

Comment: `_inventoryItemView` is added on the nib

Comment: That fixed it. Since I was initializing from the nib and in the code, the `drawRect:` was running twice. I just added a setter method for the variable, so I could add it to the already initialized view. Thanks so much for the help.